# SQL query expression in Windows Phone

Tags: c#

I have a DB - ScoreDB and table - ScoreTable with properties Name and Score. I want to display the Score in descending order:

```
t = from ScoreTable s in scoreDB.ScoreTable
                    orderby s.Score descending
                    select s;
```

Error in line:

```
GameScoreCollection = new ObservableCollection<ScoreTable>(t);
```

«The member 'BrainGainWP.ScoreTable.Score' has no supported translation to SQL.».
But if the order Name that all works:

```
t = from ScoreTable s in scoreDB.ScoreTable
                    orderby s.Name descending
                    select s;
```

table code:

```
[Table]
public class ScoreTable : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{       
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
  }

    private string _Name;

    [Column]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Name");
                _Name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column]
    private int  _Score;
    public int  Score
    {
        get
        {
            return _Score;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Score != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Score");
                _Score = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Score");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have `[Column]` on your private variable `Score`, not on the public:

```
private int  _Score;
[Column]
public int  Score
{
    get
    {
        return _Score;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_Score != value)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("Score");
            _Score = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Score");
        }
    }
}
```